# Xcode Ignoring import

Tags: swift, xcode, import

I have just installed Xcode 11 and when I try to create new fresh project with the SwiftUI check mark selected it returns an error.

Not able to build and run successfully.

> File 'ContentView.swift' is part of module 'SwiftUI'; ignoring import

**ContentView.swift**

[image]

> Use of undeclared type 'View'

**SceneDelegate.swift**

[image]

> Use of unresolved identifier 'UIHostingController'

I have tried removing all derived data and also set command-line tools to 11

Comment: Are you macOS 10.15 ?

Comment: No using version 10.14.5

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Your project is named `SwiftUI` - please try using a different name.

Comment: Yes let me try with different name

Comment: It's working now i forgot that we can't use class name :)

Comment: @PinkeshGjr An app is still a `Swift module` - and it gets resolved as a dependency before the actual framework. So `import SwiftUI` meant `import the app module`, hence the import being ignored by Xcode

Comment: I had the same issue when I created a MacOs/SwiftUI project named CoreData!

Answer (score 2):

## Detailed Answer

Each project you create has a `module` with the same name as the project. So there are **two** SwifUI modules here:

1. The actual `SwiftUI`
2. The project itself

Xcode always takes the nearest definition as the default. So your `SwiftUI` is closer than the system's `SwiftUI`. But you **are** in the project's module already! So Xcode ignores the import.

A very common mistake is to name **the project** same as one of the using frameworks! (e.g. `CoreData`, `SwiftUI`, `SceneKit`, `Metal`)

## Solution

As Matteo mentioned in his answer, **Don't** name your project *same* with another module. Change it to anything else.

---

**Note that** It could appear as an error too. For example, if you name your project `CoreData` and using *SwiftUI*, the error appears as `Circular dependency error`:

> Circular dependency between modules 'CoreData' and 'SwiftUI'

Because Xcode gets confused about modules and can not detect what the real issue is.

---

## How can we access our module's classes instead of the system's module?

Imagine you have a `class` named `Section` in a custom framework called `MyProject` and you imported it alongside the `SwiftUI`.

```
import SwiftUI
import MyProject

Section // <- This could be either SwiftUI's section or MyProject's Section
```

To make it clear for the compiler (and anyone else), you should call the module before the class name:

```
SwiftUI.Section // <- This returns the SwiftUI's Section

MyProject.Section // <- This returns the MyProject's Section
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with different project name. With **SwiftUI**, it will always show compilation error. Just change the name and enjoy coding with **SwiftUI**

Comment: You basically retyped Matteo's answer. Don't duplicate answer without meaningful purposes.