# Failed to import SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just upgraded to xcode 11 yesterday and tried to test out the new elements of SwiftUI.

I am seeing error messages that say: `Use of undeclared type 'View'`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

update: I just set a random name "test" for this project and did not put project name as "SwiftUI"

[image: Click here to see image]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505797/swiftui-ignoring-import?

Comment: I also checked this problem, the author did put his project name as swiftui. I did not, I just create a project with name: test

Comment: What happens if you remove the rest of your code and type `import Foundation; func test() -> some BinaryInteger { return 1 }`

Comment: It has compiler error because of some BinaryInteger, it says "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' "

Comment: @JohnM. I appreciate your help. Here is how i solved this problem: The new Xcode does not update my toolchain, It was still with swift 5.0. So I installed the newest swift 5.1, and the issue has solved.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is named "SwiftUI", the `import SwiftUI` line is trying to import your own project, not Apple's framework, causing this error. Try using a different project name.

Comment: Hello,I did not put my project name as "swiftui"

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out the problem.
The new Xcode does not update my toolchain, It was still with swift 5.0.
So I downloaded the newest swift 5.1 and installed, and the issue has solved.

Comment: That’s what I was starting to suspect, as it didn’t recognize the `some` keyword.